# Drupal site page slowness (this is a different from other questions on same topic)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drupal, drupal-7

Facing the drupal slowness issue. But have a very different issue than the others mentioned.

I disabled all the content also the drupal header for a drupal page of a specific content type.

Still the time taken by this page to load is above 20 secs!

I took help of YSlow and NET firebug panels.

Upon looking at them, noticed:

JS and CSS files inclusion individually takes 3 to 2 secs, and there are fair bit of inclusions happening, as a result it takes like 20 secs.

But i am not able to figure out, why the js and css inclusions are taking so much time. (this includes normal drupal core js and css files as well)

Answer (score 0):

http://shvetsgroup.com/blog/optimizing-javascript-and-css-files-drupal this is what i am studying for now.

Answer (score 0):

Install "Boost" module. Boost creates static HTML copies of pages for anonymous users. It delivers pages quite fast because it skips most (almost all) of the Drupal bootstrapping process.

If Boost doesn't make your website fly when you're an anonymous user, then the problem is in the server, not in Drupal.

Comment: aaargh... well, the basic reasoning still applies. I mean, are you sure Drupal is the one to blame? Including files is a very simple process, it should take very little time.